# Assign Semi Path to a variable

Tags: command-line, scripts, directory, playonlinux, alias

How can i assign only the first 4 words of a  path to a variable 
for example:
my current working directory is  **/home/Foo/Documents/Programs/ShellScripts/Butler**

and i want assign a variable with path of only first 4 words i mean my variable should be **SPTH='/home/Foo/Documents/Programs**' how can i do it

I want to perform this operation at  work that i have many different working repo's so what i want is  to create a alias in my bashrc so that when i call a variable it should chnage my directory to the first four words i mean first 4 directory's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use cut to get desired fields from your path:

```bsh
SPTH=$(cut -d / -f-5 <<< $PWD)
```

Comment: Thank you @bacon it worked i used it in my bashrc as  alias root='cd $(cut -d / -f-6 <<< $PWD)'

Comment: Please put double-quotes around the expression and the variable, or you could hit problems. `SPTH="$(cut -d / -f-5 <<< "$PWD")"`

Comment: can you give me an example?

Comment: @DEV if you are going to use the substitution directly in an alias like that you need to quote alias ```root='cd "$(cut -d / -f-6 <<< $PWD)"'```